# Sending SMS on event registration

Tags: scheduled-reminders, civirules

We'd like to send an SMS with the event title, start time and info page to contacts who've been registered to attend an event.

Theoretically, we should be able to do this with scheduled reminders, but haven't been able to get that working. It is setup is as follows:

[image]

We've also looked at using CiviRules to send that out, but as that relies on setting up a message template, we weren't able to add in the event tokens that we'd need.

Is anyone able to give any insight on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely use CiviRules. Why can't it use event tokens? If there's a specific shortcoming, why not log it with the team? I've a feeling some work may be done on it in the UK CiviSprint next week... ;)

Comment: From what I've been able to gather, the CiviRules SMS API uses a message template as the basis of the SMS. When setting up the message template through 'Mailings > Message Templates', those event fields don't appear as options.

When I've copied and pasted the SMS content from the Scheduled Reminders settings (that in the screenshot above), the tokens themselves appear in the SMS that the contact receives rather than the event details.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible to use event tokens :( https://civicrm.org/comment/8417#comment-8417

Comment: The shortcoming here then is "event tokens aren't being processed in CiviRules SMS messages". Log it as an issue on their GitHub, and with any luck some happy-go-lucky hacker-for-hire might address it next week ;)

Comment: Fingers crossed! If anyone's looking for this in the future, the issue is logged here: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/issues/111

Comment: @termdark, if you like the answer put a tick on it!